# How Google Chrome's chrome://tracing implemented?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is it specific to X86_* CPU? Or applicable for all?

What is the library/3rd_party code which used to make this work?

Comment: It's generated by a Python script, have you looked in to the source code?

Comment: Really? You mean Chrome executable also includes a python runtime? I don't think so. Yet to get into the source. I want to know how the profiling data is generated not how it is populated.

Comment: When you look at the source of `chrome://tracing` you will find a comment on the top saying: "This file is generated by generate_about_tracing_contents.py". But you are right, it is probably generated as a part of Chrome build process, not on the fly. Anyway, I found a method responsible for receiving tracing data - `onSystemTraceDataCollected` in `trace.js`. According to the comment above it is called "by tracing c++ code when new system trace data arrives".

Comment: Thanks @KonradDzwinel! What I want to know is how they are getting the profiling info like a function call & call counter ,.. etc.. I will try to dive into the source code. [I feel it is not straightforward to get these kind of trace details without an utility library]. May be google-perf-tools code.google.com/p/gperftools helping chrome to get these. But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I understood how about://tracing works without digging the source code.

http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/trace-event-profiling-tool/tracing-event-instrumentation explains the more details about Chrome's tracing.

Actually it is a manually added instrumentation points inserted into the source by the developers.

```
#include <base/debug/trace_event.h>
```

Above header contains all the abstractions to ease that.